# Moving multiple cursors to next or previous space in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to move multiple cursors to the next/prev space (or possibly other character) in VScode?

Quite often I want to move all the cursors in VSCode to the next space. Pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> will move them all to the beginning of the line, and pressing <kbd>End</kbd> will move then all to the end. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> moves them forward and backward a word I often want to move them all to the next space so

```
aaa-bbb-ccc ddd-eee-fff
ggg-hhh iii-jjj
kkk-lll-mmm-ooo ppp-qqq-rrr-sss ttt
```

If my cursors are at the beginning of each of those lines how can I get them to be at first space in each line? Next word won't work because it will stop at the dashes.

Searching and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> can sometimes cover it but not always and further it's tedious (select the area, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, try to enter some regular expression that only selects the things you want), as you can see above, searching for space will fail. You can come up with a regular expression that will match but that just adds to the tedium.

Is there a way to go move all the cursors to forward or back to some specific character?

Common wants would be, next space, next comma, next open or close paren, brace, square bracket, angle bracket, next quote, next double quote, etc....  Ideally I'd be nice to do it with or without select. In other words I might want to move to the start of the line, then select to the first space in each line. Or, once I somehow manage to get the cursor at the first space I might want to select from there to the first open paren.

Comment: Do you want this to operate only within each current line?  And input only a single character - like a space, but not move to the next multi-character text string like `abc`?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a simplified extension that allows you to jump with/without selecting simply with a keybinding and the character you want to go to.  It will only take a single character and doesn't use a regex so it is not nearly as powerful as @rioV8's extension.

But it only requires a single keybinding to go forward and select to any character, for example.  In this demo I trigger the same keybinding ( I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but it could be anything) on both sets of selections - the first time I press a <kbd>Space</kbd> after the keybinding and the second time I press a <kbd>C</kbd>.  You can't see those keypresses as they are captured by the extension and not displayed.

[image: jump demo]

Extension link: [Jump and Select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select)

### Extension Commands

- **jump-and-select.jumpForwardOnly**     -   Moves to the next occurrence of the character.
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- **jump-and-select.jumpForwardSelect**     -   Selects from the cursor to the next occurrence of the character.
    <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- **jump-and-select.jumpBackwardOnly**     -   Moves to the previous occurrence of the character.
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>
- **jump-and-select.jumpBackwardSelect**     -   Selects from the cursor to the previous occurrence of the character.
    <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

### How It Works

Choose one of your keybindings, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to jump forward.

1. Trigger that command: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>,
2. Type a character (it will not be shown), and
3. Cursor moves to that next character.

---

and you can easily jump through characters like this (going from `"` to `"`:

[image: multiMode jumping]

It is called `MultiMode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and use the `moveby.regex` command

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": " ",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```

If you want to have the cursors before the space use: `"properties": ["next", "start"]`

For the previous space use: `"properties": ["prev", "start"]`